# How to redirect a subdomain to specific directory including a query?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect my subdomains to directories, and this has worked so far. But one subdomain needs to go to a directory including a specific query.

So while this works to rewrite resume.domain.com to domain.com/resume (so it leaves the URL, which is important to me)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^resume\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!resume/).*)$ /resume/$1 [NC,L]
```

This to rewrite cv.lexpostma.me to the same directory, but with a ?nl (yes, no =something) query, doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cv\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!cv/).*)$ /resume/index.php?nl$1 [NC,L]
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the final URL you are seeing in your browser for `http://cv.domain.com/`?